# C# Stop a class from serializing

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I need to stop a class from getting serialized if it is in a collection, since I don't have control over the parent class property that is returning the collection. Without implementing ISerializable is there any solution?

```
public class NonControllable{
    Collection children;
}

public class MyClass : NonControllable {
    // NEED TO STOP Serializing children property.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since yoy have the [xml] tag, you would want (at the parent level):

```
[XmlIgnore]
public Foo Bar {...}
```

however, you can't control this at the type level. The type exposing the member has to define it.

An alternative is to use `XmlAttributeOverrides` when creating the `XmlSerializer`.

Note that `ISerializable` makes no impact on xml serialization; you would need `IXmlSerializable`, which is (IMO) a pain to implement robustly.

Answer (score 1):

Simply mark the property with a non serializable attribute and the serialization will not occur.

See the following example;

```
public class MyClass : NonControllable {

    // Property that is not serialized.
    [NonSerialized()] 
    public string myProperty; 
}
```

Comment: the NonSerialized and Serializable attributes have nothing to do with XML serialization

Comment: Cant use the above since the property is already there in the parent class